# Powershell error " incomplete string token"

Tags: azure, powershell, github, yaml, azure-powershell

I'm trying to run a workflow file to deploy function app in Azure with new resource group and my workflow yml file fails to run the step and throws an error:

```
ParserError: D:\a\_temp\2ef5a91f-aee0-4906-9e6e-ab5e5233530f.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  …  -Name "az-xxx-xxx-rg-businessfuncappxayb" -Location "North Europe" `
     |                                                                          ~
     | Incomplete string token.
```

YML script:

```
  name: Resource Group Creation
  uses: azure/powershell@v1
  with:
      azPSVersion: latest
      inlineScript:
        Select-AzSubscription -Subscription ${{ github.event.inputs.businessSubscriptionId }}| `

        New-AzResourceGroup -Name "az-dna-113-rg-businessfuncappxayb" -Location "North Europe" `
      failOnStandardError: $true
```

YML script:

```
  name: Resource Group Creation
  uses: azure/powershell@v1
  with:
      azPSVersion: latest
      inlineScript:
        Select-AzSubscription -Subscription ${{ github.event.inputs.businessSubscriptionId }}| `

        New-AzResourceGroup -Name "az-dna-113-rg-businessfuncappxayb" -Location "North Europe" `
      failOnStandardError: $true
```

Comment: In your YAML script, it seems like the PowerShell script is not properly formatted. Specifically, the inlineScript section is missing the PowerShell script code. You need to replace the empty PowerShell script with the actual code that creates the resource group. For PowerShell within a YAML file, you should use the | symbol to denote a multi-line string. Also, ensure that you're not using backticks (`) for line continuation as you would in a normal PowerShell

Comment: You’ve got a trailing backtick on the end of your ```New-AzResourceGroup``` command - you don’t put a backtick on the *last* line of a multi line command as it tells Powershell there’s still more pipeline instructions / parameters to come (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.4#line-continuation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error suggests there is a syntax issue with your **YAML** script. It indicates that an incomplete string token exists within your PowerShell script.

You can pass service principal's details in  **JSON** object in a `GitHub` action and create a secret named `AZURE_CREDENTIALS`, which you can use to authenticate with Azure.

```json
    {
        "clientId": "<GUID>",
        "clientSecret": "<secret>",
        "subscriptionId": "<GUID>",
        "tenantId": "<GUID>",
        (...)
    }
```

Here is the **YAML** script that utilizes `PowerShell` within the **YAML** file to create an Azure resource.

```
    on: [push]
    name: AzureARMSample
    
    jobs:
      build-and-deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        env:
          ResourceGroupName: github-action-arm-rg
          ResourceGroupLocation: "australiaeast"
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@master
        - uses: azure/login@v1
          with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
            enable-AzPSSession: true
        - uses: Azure/Powershell@v1
          with:
            inlineScript: |
              #!/bin/bash
              New-AzResourceGroup -Name "az-dna-113-rg-businessfuncappxayb" -Location "North Europe"
            azPSVersion: "latest"
```

The deployment has been successfully completed.

[image]

After running the `GitHub action`, the resource group was created successfully.

[image]

Reference:  [Use the Azure login action with a service principal secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/connect-from-azure?tabs=azure-portal,linux#use-the-azure-login-action-with-a-service-principal-secret)